# How to mock An Interface Java PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I m trying to mock an interface.

```
public interface FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager {
List<FlowCopyParams> findByAppli(String application, String sourcePattern)
        throws FlowCopyParamsBusinessException;
```

}

In my code, when i call this method **findByAppli**, i would like to return a list of FlowCopyParams.

```
List<FlowCopyParams> lstFlowCopyParams = flowCopyParamsBusinessManager.findByAppli(
                    "TOTO","TATA);
```

Here my try in the class test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void mockBeanIn() throws Exception {
List<FlowCopyParams> flowCopyParamsList = new ArrayList<>();

PowerMockito.spy(FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager.class);
PowerMockito.when(FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager.class, "findByAppli",  Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(flowCopyParamsList);
}
```

I have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

I don't know why because the method findByAppli must *have two string parameters*, and i put **Mockito.anyString()** and i still have **IllegalArgumentException**.

Any clue ?

Thxs.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use PowerMockito, and as its an Interface, theres no need to spy() as you are not relying on any non mocked logic.

It can be done like this, in your test class define a class variable.

```
private FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager flowCopyParamsBusinessManagerMock;
```

In an `@Before` annotated method:

```
flowCopyParamsBusinessManagerMock = Mockito.mock(FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager.class);
List<FlowCopyParams> flowCopyParamsList = new ArrayList<>();
when(flowCopyParamsBusinessManagerMock 
.findByAppli(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(flowCopyParamsList);
```

Then refer to `flowCopyParamsBusinessManagerMock` in your tests.

Comment: I don t even know what spy does concretely.

Comment: Spy allows you to use parts (methods) of the original concrete implementation of the object whereas mock will not provide any of the original implementation.

Comment: put @PrepareForTest({interacename.class}) at the top and mock it.

Answer (score 1):

My test did not work because I was trying to spy the class and not on the instance of FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager.class .

First , we have to create the mock :

```
FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager mockFlowCopyParamsBusinessManager = PowerMockito.mock(FlowCopyParamsBusinessManager.class);
```

Then , spy the instance :

```
PowerMockito.spy(mockFlowCopyParamsBusinessManager);
PowerMockito.when(mockFlowCopyParamsBusinessManager, "findByAppli", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(flowCopyParamsList);
```

It works as well !

Answer (score 0):

I did this put this  @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) at the top of the class. then mock Object with PowerMockito.mock(MyMock.class); This way use can mock a interface or final class.