# How to mock an interface's reference which is initialized by MyBatis?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, dao, powermock

Before marking duplicate of this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267199/how-to-mock-an-interface-java-powermockito), understand that the answer doesn't solve my problem. The answer gives a solution where I use an `when()` in the current method. In my problem, `UserDao` is being initialized else where inside the method under test and mocked object cannot be passed.

---

There is an interface's reference which is initialized by MyBatis. I cannot directly mock it in the test because the object isn't passed into the test's subject. I have to PowerMock it by mocking the Constructor. Since, there is no constructor calling to the interface, PowerMock throws an exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.AbstractConstructorExpectationSetup.withAnyArguments(AbstractConstructorExpectationSetup.java:100)
```

Here is how code looks like

```
class UserServiceTest{

    @AutoWired
    UserService userService;

    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;//This is a reference to the interface (UserDao) which is mapped using MyBatis

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
           //The Program fails at the below statement
           PowerMockito.whenNew(UserDao.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(userDao);        
    @Test
    public void testFetchDetails() throws Exception {
          when(userDao.fetchDetails(any(ParameterOne.class)).thenReturn(null);
          assertThat(userService.fetchDetails(new ParameterOne())).isNull();
    }

}
```

If I run the program without PowerMock, actual Database is accessed and returns correct results. Accessing database also leads to slowing of Test's runtime increasing up to 500ms.

How do I mock `UserDao userDao`? If I cannot mock how to perform Unit Test in such a case. I cannot change the code I'm testing.

P.S. If you still suggest me to avoid using PowerMock, please suggest a "better" alternative in the situation.

P.P.S Mind you, I am not testing the Dao Layer rather the service which uses the Dao Layer hence, I have to mock DaoLayer to check if service's behaviour is correct or not.

Comment: Is that the complete code of your test? As per the [docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) you should annotate the test with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` & `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application was a spring-boot application. I used `@InjectMocks` for the class under test and `@Mock` for any object which is in need of mocking.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
class UserServiceTest{
    @InjectMocks
    UserService userService;

    @Mock
    UserDao userDao;//This is a reference to the interface (UserDao) which is mapped using MyBatis

    ...
}
```

This worked and I could directly use when()/given() on the mock objects.